# Finding an element in a nested table using selenium python bindings

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have to find "required element" a web page in the following HTML code using python selenium bindings:

```
    < div id = "xxx">
      < table = "first">
         <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td class = "mmm1">
              <td class = "yyyy1">
                   <table class = "second">
                     <tbody>
                       <tr class = "bbb">
                           <td></td>
                           <td></td>
                           <td></td>
                           <td>
                               < input id = "required element" type="image" onclick = "behavior defined here as a script">
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                       </tbody>
                      </table>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                 </table>
```

Here is my py script using selenium:

```
    element_found = browser_open.find_element_by_xpath("//tr/td[contains(@class,'yyyy1')]")
```

element_table = element_found.find_element_by_class_name("second")

I am not able to find the table element (second) which is preceeded by "yyyy1". 
The above line of element_table gives an error always on not able to find the element. The intent is to find the =>"required element" and perform click action on it.

How to find table within an element of table column ? also will this table be a child of that element?

Please help here for the same.

Comment: does this exception also raise if to use `browser_open.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@class="second"]')` ?

Comment: yes, if I try to access anything below the td it fails - last successful find is till the td find through class name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might need to add some time for page to completely render:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

xpath = '//td[@class="yyyy1"]/table[@class="second"]/input[@id="required element"]'
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("Required element still could not be found!")
```

This should allow to wait up to 20 seconds for required element and then raise TimeOut exception.

Let me know if element still not found

Comment: Thanks a lot Andersson for the help...still I am not able to find the element and script is throwing an error. I tried by increasing the hold time to 30 also. Same effect. Please do help on next steps.

Comment: Check if element is located inside an `<iframe>`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked the tree and it is under an iframe, here is the breakdown:    <iframe class = "aaa" src = "yyy"  > <#doc> <form id = "mmm"> <div id = "xxx" > starting as above mentioned...how shall i handle this now?

Comment: OK. So you should switch to this `iframe` before searching for element in it. Try to add this line before click: `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="aaa"]'))`. Then after required operations on `iframe` you can switch back to main page `HTML` with `driver.switch_to_default_content()`

Comment: thanks for the help...it is still failing...here is my actual code: `code` xpath = '//td[@class="ui-toolbar-container-right"]/table[@class="ui-toolbar-table-right"]/input[@id="xxxx"]'
browser_open.switch_to_frame(browser_open.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="iframe_xxxx"]'))
try:
 WebDriverWait(browser_open, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()
 browser_open.switch_to_default_content()
except TimeoutException:
    print("Required element still could not be found!")

Comment: I have a query ..if I can reach the td (class container then without switching iframe before), but not the table in the following tree...but iframe definition is parent to all of them...so will it help only for the table element? Please help. thanks a lot again...